# JavaScript group by key nested properties

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm having an object

```
{
    "changeRequest": [{
            "acrId": 11,
            "ccrId": "",
            "message": "test message"
        },
        {
            "acrId": 12,
            "ccrId": "123456",
            "message": "Car Generation successful."
        }
    ],
    "assessmentDetails": [{
            "qId": 1749
        },
        {
            "crList": [{
                "compName": "Chevrolet Cobra",
                "cId": "169576",
                "acrId": 11
            }],
            "qId": 1737
        },
        {
            "qId": 1738,
                "crList": [{
                "compName": "Ferrari",
                "cId": "169586",
                "acrId": 11
            }],
        },
        {
            "crList": [{
                    "compName": "Mercedez Benz",
                    "cId": "169575",
                    "acrId": 12
                },
                {
                    "compName": "Isdera",
                    "cId": "169577",
                    "acrId": 12
                }
            ],
            "qId": 1739
        }
    ]
}
```

So I'm using angular and using `ngFor` I'm looping `changeRequest` and displaying the ccrId if its not empty in an ordered list. and If its empty I'm displaying the message.

Now, I have an requirement where I need to group the the `compName` and display as nested list based on `acrId`

O/P

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    test message
    <ul>
      <li>Chevrolet Cobra</li>
      <li>Ferrari</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>
    123456
    <ul>
      <li>Mercedez Benz</li>
      <li>Isdera</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```

HTML

```
<ol>
                    <ng-container>
                        <li *ngFor="let crObj of formatedBfaData">
                            <ng-container
                                *ngTemplateOutlet="crObj.crId ? displayCrLink : displayCrErrorMessage; context:{ $implicit: crObj}">
                            </ng-container>
                            <ng-template #displayCrLink let-crObj>
                                <div class="pb-2">{{ crObj.crId }}</div>
                            </ng-template>
    
                            <ng-template #displayCrErrorMessage let-crObj>
                                <div class="text-danger">{{crObj.name}}</div>
                            </ng-template>
                        </li>
                    </ng-container>
                </ol>
```

TS

```
this.formatedBfaData = data.changeRequest.map(crObj => {
        return {crId: crObj.ccrId !== '' ? crObj.ccrId: null, name: crObj.message}
      })
```

I'm not sure how to group the required values, would be great if someone can help through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find in every `crList` which one match the wanted `acrId`.

```js
const data = {
    "changeRequest": [{
            "acrId": 11,
            "ccrId": "",
            "message": "test message"
        },
        {
            "acrId": 12,
            "ccrId": "123456",
            "message": "Car Generation successful."
        }
    ],
    "assessmentDetails": [{
            "qId": 1749
        },
        {
            "crList": [{
                "compName": "Chevrolet Cobra",
                "cId": "169576",
                "acrId": 11
            }],
            "qId": 1737
        },
        {
            "qId": 1738,
                "crList": [{
                "compName": "Ferrari",
                "cId": "169586",
                "acrId": 11
            }],
        },
        {
            "crList": [{
                    "compName": "Mercedez Benz",
                    "cId": "169575",
                    "acrId": 12
                },
                {
                    "compName": "Isdera",
                    "cId": "169577",
                    "acrId": 12
                }
            ],
            "qId": 1739
        }
    ]
};

const transformed = data.changeRequest.map(({ acrId, message }) => [message, data.assessmentDetails.filter(({ crList }) => crList).flatMap(({ crList }) => crList.filter((item) => item.acrId === acrId).map(({ compName }) => compName))]);

console.log(transformed)
console.log(Object.fromEntries(transformed))
```

Comment: I'm displaying `ccrId` at parent level, only if its empty I'm displaying `message`. You're displaying message directly which any checks